# C# - Load existing system environment variables when the current process don't have them loaded

Tags: c#, environment-variables, .net-assembly

On Windows, I have a C# assembly that is COM visible. It references other assemblies to control an application in the machine. It works fine.

However, under Apache Web Server and using CGI, it doesn't work. After doing some  debuging, I found out that the problem is that, while running under Apache's CGI, the environment variables SYSTEMROOT and SYSTEMDRIVE, which aparently are needed by the referenced assemblies, are not loaded.

I can configure Apache to pass those environemtn variables too, but before doing so, I'd really like to know if there's some command I can put on my C# COM visible assembly to make it load environment variables as if it was, let's say, the SYSTEM user or something like that, so it doesn't have to relay on the environment passed by the starting application.

How do you force loading an existent system environment variable in C#, **when IT IS NOT SET in the current process** (or it was process-deleted by the launching process)?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

**EDIT 1 - ADDED INFO:** Just to make it more clear (as I see in the current answers it's not so clear): Apache intendedly deletes a lot of environment variables for CGI processes. It's not that Apache cannot see them, it can, but it won't pass them to CGI processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** Marco's answer was great and technically answered my question - except that I found out that the environment variables SYSTEMROOT and SYSTEMDRIVE are not really set in the registry where all environment variables are set, so, the chosen answer works for all variables except those two, which I specified in the OP.

SYSTEMROOT is defined on the registry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRoot, and apparently (after more research), SYSTEMDRIVE is generated as a substring of SYSTEMDRIVE.

So, to get SYSTEMDRIVE and SYSTEMROOT from registry and load them into the environment:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace MySpace
{
    public class Setup
    {
        public Setup()
        {
            SetUpEnvironment();
        }
        private void SetUpEnvironment()
        {
            string test_a = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SYSTEMDRIVE", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            string test_b = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SYSTEMROOT", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            if (test_a == null || test_a.Length == 0 || test_b == null || test_b.Length == 0)
            {
                string RegistryPath = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion";
                string SYSTEMROOT = (string) Registry.GetValue(RegistryPath, "SystemRoot", null);
                if (SYSTEMROOT == null)
                {
                    throw new System.ApplicationException("Cannot access registry key " + RegistryPath);
                }
                string SYSTEMDRIVE = SYSTEMROOT.Substring(0, SYSTEMROOT.IndexOf(':') + 1);
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SYSTEMROOT", SYSTEMROOT, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SYSTEMDRIVE", SYSTEMDRIVE, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just call `Setup setup = new Setup();` from other classes. And that's it. :-)

Comment: Glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("variable", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

I did a small test and it is working:

```
        //has the value
        string a = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TMP");

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TMP", null);

        //does not have has the value
        a = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TMP");

        //has the value
        a = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TMP", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable
```

see reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx).

e.g.

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");        
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(".");
lock(info)
{      
    Console.WriteLine("Directory Info:   "+info.FullName);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that relay on existent/set environment variables? Remember I'm saying those variables are not set in the Apache started process - Apache only sends HTTP-Request related variables in the environment to processes started by CGI.

Comment: your title is misleading, you are saying "load" system vars, how can you load a var that does not exist yet? Very confusing.

Comment: It exists. It's just not passed to the current process. That's why I want to load it.

Comment: Ridiculous, rephase your question and never take wrong as correct!

Comment: Ridiculous is your attitude. You say it's "very confusing", but you are the one confusing the meaning of "load environment variables" with "GET environment variables". The question was exactly "how to LOAD environment variables", with an explanation (that you didn't read) of why they existed but were not loaded, and Marco's answer was correct, your's was not.

Answer (score 0):

Are the variables set as system wide?

If they are not, that is what you need to do, otherwise create user variables for the user the COM is running under.

Comment: Yes, the variables are set for the whole system (every copy of Windows has SYSTEMROOT and SYSTEMDRIVE defined). The user starting the process also can see them. The problem is that Apache only sends HTTP-Request related variables in the environment to processes started by CGI, so I need a way for the assembly to load those variables from the system/registry even when they're not set in the current process environment.

Comment: But then the problem is related to something else because if the variables are set as system wide, then the clr process should have access to them. The Apache is surely not creating a wrapper environment around the process running the CGI.

Comment: As a last resort try using a call to the Win32 API  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
internal static extern int GetEnvironmentVariable(string lpName, StringBuilder lpValue, int size);

Comment: Also did you try this key in the registry? HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment

Comment: Apache DOES hide environment variables to any child processes. It's a security thing and can be configured to specify other variables to be passed to child processes, I just wanted to solve it in the assembly and not in Apache. Look at the edits on the OP to see how I resolved it. Thanks anyway. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.  I cannot state with any certainty that this has once and for all driven a stake through the heart of the vampire, but amazingly enough, the error has disappeared (for now).  The odd thing is that access to the statement

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("variable", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

is a real oddity in the debugger.  It does not show up in Intellisense and does not even appear to fire, which leads me to suspect, **which you all knew already,** that this is some sort of magic runtime object **Environment** that has no instantiation in the debugger but also can be benignly jumped over.  Oh well.

Oh and **I should mention** that after you see that error, you will note oddities in your Windows OS, which is worrisome.  In particular, you will see, if you try to use the Control Panel /System/Advanced Properties (whatever) that it cannot load the dialog for the environment variables any more, indicating that **%windir% has been seriously hosed** (compromised) across all applications. Bad bad bad....